# Which is the right method of analysis for data over one time-period?

Tags: econometrics, survey, panel-data

I am in the process of designing a survey that will collect data from users of services provided by my organization.  We will collect data from all those users (other smaller organizations) working with us; therefore, we will have data about the whole population.

We will design the survey in such a way that we get only numeric observations: continuous, discrete and categorical variables.

At first I thought I would use panel data analysis, but the problem is that I will -at first- have data over just one time-period.

The question then is, can I still use panel data analysis? Which other method would it fit best this kind of dataset?

Comment: That's standard cross-sectional analysis.

Comment: Oh mine...obvious! I think I gotta get back to the books.  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: I don't understand your question.
Usually, you have a research question and then you try to think about a way to collect data so that you can answer that question, not the other way around!

Comment: If you observe the full population, you might be happy with summarizing descriptive statistics. Is there any specific intention guiding your choice of analysis method?